# Как сверстать данный элемент угольник?

Tags: html, css

Никак не могу понять, как сверстать данный угольник, у меня получается он полукруглым[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 6):

Пожалуйста!

```css
.blockquote .quote {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-top: 4px solid #000000;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #000000;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.blockquote .quote:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  right: 70px;
  bottom: -30px;
  border: 15px solid;
  border-color: #000000 #000000 transparent transparent;
}

.blockquote .quote:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  right: 74px;
  bottom: -20px;
  border: 11px solid;
  border-color: #ffffff #ffffff transparent transparent;
}

.autor {
  text-align: right;
  padding: 0 20px;
  line-height: 100px;
}

.autor img {
  float: right;
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
  -moz-border-radius: 100px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 100px;
  -o-border-radius: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  margin: 0 0 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="blockquote">
  <div class="quote">Я помню чудное мгновенье:<br> Передо мной явилась ты,<br> Как мимолетное виденье,<br> Как гений чистой красоты.</div>
</div>
<div class="autor">Автор: А. С. Пушкин <img alt="" src="https://www.stihi.ru/pics/2019/07/30/7939.jpg"></div>
```

Ну или вот:

```css
.blockquote .quote {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 4px solid green;
  margin: 40px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.blockquote .quote:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  left: 70px;
  top: -30px;
  border: 15px solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent green green;
}

.blockquote .quote:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  left: 74px;
  top: -20px;
  border: 11px solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent #fff #fff;
}

.autor {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0 0 0 50px;
}

.autor img {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
  -moz-border-radius: 100px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 100px;
  -o-border-radius: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}

.autor {
  padding: 0 0 0 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="autor"><img alt="" src="https://www.stihi.ru/pics/2019/07/30/7939.jpg">
  <p><b>Автор:</b><br>А. С. Пушкин</p>
</div>
<div class="blockquote">
  <div class="quote">Я помню чудное мгновенье:<br> Передо мной явилась ты,<br> Как мимолетное виденье,<br> Как гений чистой красоты.</div>
</div>
```

И еще один вариант, как на картинке:

```css
.blockquote {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  width: auto;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 3px solid green;
  margin: 40px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.blockquote:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  left: 70px;
  top: -30px;
  border: 20px solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent green green;
}

.blockquote:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  left: 74px;
  top: -23px;
  border: 16px solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent #fff #fff;
}

.blockquote:before,
.blockquote:after {
  -moz-transform: rotate(-25deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-25deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-25deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-25deg);
  transform: rotate(-25deg);
}

.quote_text {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.quote:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.autor {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0 0 0 50px;
}

.autor img {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
  -moz-border-radius: 100px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 100px;
  -o-border-radius: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}

.autor {
  padding: 0 0 0 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="autor"><img alt="" src="https://www.stihi.ru/pics/2019/07/30/7939.jpg">
  <p><b>Автор:</b><br>А. С. Пушкин</p>
</div>
<div class="blockquote">
  <div class="quote">
    <div class="quote_text">Я помню чудное мгновенье:<br> Передо мной явилась ты,<br> Как мимолетное виденье,<br> Как гений чистой красоты.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: И ни один не похож на вопрос...

Comment: Теперь третий похож :)

Answer (score 5):

```css
div {
  clip-path: polygon(0 21%, 33% 21%, 24% 0, 51% 20%, 100% 21%, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Можете поиграться с полигоном